# Why is the built in delete predicate not working on this dynamic list? (Prolog)

Tags: list, dynamic, prolog

I have a dynamic list:

```
:- dynamic queue/1.

queue([Bob,Steve,Richard,Katie]).
```

and a predicate:

```
delete_person(Person) :-
   queue(Q),
   retractall(queue(_)),
   delete(Q, Person, Z),
   assert(queue(Z)).
```

Logically, this follows to me, but I've obviously made a mistake as the list stays the same after running the predicate `delete_person`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple problems in this snippet. First of all, you have posted the following program:

```
:- dynamic queue/1.

queue([Bob,Steve,Richard,Katie]).

delete_person(Person) :-
   queue(Q),
   delete(Q, Person, Z).

assert(queue(Z)).
```

This means that you have a *fact* of the form `assert/1` in your code. That's probably *not* what you intended to write.

Second, if you correct `delete_person/1` to read:

```
delete_person(Person) :-
   queue(Q),
   delete(Q, Person, Z),
   assert(queue(Z)).
```

then we *still* have the following **singleton warning**:

```
Singleton variables: [Bob,Steve,Richard,Katie]
```

This is because `Bob`, `Steve` etc. are all (probably inadvertently) Prolog **variables**.

If you correct this to read:

```
queue([bob,steve,richard,katie]).
```

Then at least the program *compiles without warnings*.

Now we can talk about the actual issue:

```
?- delete_person(bob).
true.

?- queue(Q).
Q = [bob, steve, richard, katie] ;
Q = [steve, richard, katie].
```

Next time, please include:

1. the **query you tried**
2. the **expected result**
3. the **obtained result**.

In the case above, why is the *queue not modified*?

That's because you inadvertently only **add an additional fact** for `queue/1`, but you **do not remove the already existing fact**.

That's a **typical** mistake when modifying the global database. You are already getting a glimpse of the issues that await you if you use Prolog like an imperative language. It will make your code extremely hard to reason about, yield several hard to debug problems, makes it hard to *test* your code, and generally combines the disadvantages of imperative languages with their severe lack of generality.

---

A **declarative** solution of your program is to think in terms of **relations** between queues. Think of it this way: What is the *relation* between 2 queues if a specific element is removed from the first queue, and the second queue is the same as the first queue except for that element?

For example, think about: `queue_without_element/3`, whose definition could start like this:

```
queue_without_element(Q0, E, Q) :-
    ...
```

Advantages:

1. Usable in *several directions*.
2. Can be *tested* in isolation of other predicates.
3. Is automatically *thread safe*.
4. Is almost certainly *more efficient* than modifying the global database.
5. etc.